# When to use a spinner vs a form object

Tags: user-interface, forms, textbox, spinner

When  is using a [spinner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinner_(computing)) object appropriate, rather than using a standard [text entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_box) object (a.k.a. form, or text box)?

I am looking for information on "best practices" in GUI.

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a reasonable question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking that the spinner object should be used only where it makes sense to click small incremental values up and down, e.g. small numbers like the number of copies for a print job.

Comment: Pretty much what I'd say; small, incremental values. Text fields are appropriate for longer numeric input, or where flipping through a range of values doesn't make sense (e.g. for currency, etc.).